# Convert long string into multiple short strings

Tags: c#, string, rtmp

I have a very long code that a server creates. Here is the code that is used:

```
AllGameData = "{\"queueId\":" + queueId + ",\"isRanked\"."+ isRanked + ",\"rankedTeamName\":\"" + rankedTeamName + "\",\"mapId\":" + mapId + ",\"gameTypeConfigId\":" + gameTypeConfigId + ",\"gameMode\":\"" + gameMode + ",\"gameType\":\"" + gameType + "\"}";
```

The client has to convert this string into a shorter string that only contains:

```
mapId: [int mapId]
gameMode: [string gameMode]
gameType: [string gameType]
```

If statements won't work because these are randomized.
I am not in power of the server so I can not change the method that it creates the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert that string on the jsonObject that represent it. And after that make your own string. Take the newtonsoft from nuget repository.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; // This is the namespace of Newtonsoft. 

// this are the lines
dynamic gameDataObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(AllGameData);

var newStr = string.Format("{{\"mapId\":\"{0}\", \"gameMode\":\"{1}\", \"gameType\":\"{2}\"}}", gameDataObj.mapId, gameDataObj.gameMode, gameDataObj.gameType);
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Convert this string into Json , 
Like create a class for required fields and u can serialize the string into ur object ,
this way user can get each string separately

thank you